# Deviation between spot price and implied spot price of S&P500 mini-futures

Tags: futures, arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory, theory

From Derivatives Markets (McDonald) it is stated that we may price a financial forward and, equivalently, get an implied spot price from a given futures price:
$$
F_{0, T}=S_0e^{(r-\delta)T} \implies S_0=\frac{F_{0,T}}{e^{(r-\delta)T}}
$$
Applying this to S&P500 mini-futures however, I observed a deviation in the actual and implied spot price when the market was open:

[image]

My intuition tells me this may be due to transaction cost as if not I believe there is an arbitrage opportunity, but I am unsure.

Why could this be?

Comment: A small point about the chart: the next 3 fute expirations are mid-june, mid-sep and mid-dec. There is no future expiring in mid-may and therefore that point in the chart is meaningless, should not be there IMO.

Comment: @nbbo2 The mid-may is the (current) spot-price from yesterday. Apologies for not clarifying.

Comment: You treat rates and dividends as if they would simply be the same throughout: Dividends are not [paid constantly](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/equity/sp-500-dividend-points-index-annual/#overview); interest rates are not constant either. so you need a swap curve to get exact rate for the expiry date plus the exact dividends and use appropriate daycount (Act/360 for rates for example). You still have bid and ask to take into consideration for any arbitrage opportunity (plus transaction costs and weather you can borrow invest at the risk free rate if needed).

Comment: The most obvious indication that your inputs are wrong is that taking r-d with r>d will result in F>S and not F<S as you screenshot suggests.

Comment: @AKdemy Interest rates and dividends are both transformed to be continuously compounding. Dividends are prone to only some seasonality as we are dealing with an index, and getting the exact interest rate makes little difference. It would be great if you could point more concretely to some factors as these are only marginal.

Comment: Do you agree that if r>d (as in your example), based on your formula, F must be above S and not below (as in your example)? If you have access to Bloomberg you can look at FAIR to see what values are used (based on a set of choices for swap curves and dividend projections).

Comment: Where do you get that the correct rate to discount the futures is 2.12%?